# Razor Pages Tag Helper with Dynamic Parameters Assigning Current Url as Href

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, tag-helpers

I'm running into trouble trying to set anchor tag helper parameters dynamically and looking for some help.

I have a nav that is a view component inside the shared _Layout.cshtml page that populates departments from a model.

```
@model List<DepartmentModel>
<ul class="nav">
    @foreach (var d in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <a asp-page="catalog/departments" asp-route-departmentName="@d.Name" asp-route-departmentId="@d.Id">@d.Name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Here is the InvokeAsync() from my View Component class

```
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var departments = _catalogService.GetNavDepartments();

        return View(departments);
    }
```

When I first launch the page, all the hrefs are populating correctly.

- "catalog/departments/department-name-1/department-id-1"
- "catalog/departments/department-name-2/department-id-2"
- "catalog/departments/department-name-3/department-id-3"

If I click on one of the links, like the first link for example, I go to the proper department page "catalog/departments/department-name-1/department-id-1"

However, once I click that first link and navigate to the respective page, all the nav hrefs populate to the current url "catalog/departments/department-name-1/department-id-1" instead of the originally generated hrefs. This makes it so I can't navigate to another department.

Here is my route in the Startup.cs

```
 services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                             
  options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Catalog/Departments", "{dName}/{dId}");

 });
```

Based on the convention above, it eliminates the "catalog/department" piece of the url but I added it in this description for a sense of what I'm trying to accomplish. Even if I add this template to the page that populates the "catalog/departments" url, I get the same result.

```
@page  "{dName}/{dId}"
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing?  Thanks in advance!

******** UPDATE ********

Currently, the only way I am able to get this to work is by adding the cache tag helper.

```
 <cache>
    <ul class="nav">
        @foreach (var d in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a asp-page="catalog/departments" asp-route-departmentName="@d.Name" asp-route-departmentId="@d.Id">@d.Name</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
 </cache>
```

This doesn't seem like a proper fix.  Seems more of a hack then anything.  Anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The link is generated based on `Model`. So you need to check how you reder `Model` from Controller to View. It may be the `Name` and the `Id` values are `1`.

Comment: Could you share how to inject the model? Because the way I register is `@model IndexModel`, and the anchor tag generate `<a href="/catalog/departments/department-name-3? departmentId=department-id-3">department-name-3</a>`. In addition, after click the first link, the value of model may be refreshed.

Comment: Karney - I added how I'm injecting the model and the other pieces of code in the mix. Could you elaborate on your comment "In addition, after the first link, the value of the model may be refreshed"? Thanks!

Comment: Tan - upon first launch of the page, the list is populating correctly with values department-id-1, department-id-2, department-id-3, etc. Its only after one of the links is clicked that all the hrefs change to the url of the clicked link.  So if I clicked the department-id-2 link, once the department-id-2 page displays, all the link hrefs become the department-id-2 link. I set a break point when the model populates and upon navigation to the page of the clicked link, the model populates correctly. Seems something may be happening when the component renders?